# How to prove the uniqueness of the minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I have here the definition:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector
>   space $V$ over the field $F$. The minimal polynomial for T is the (unique)
>   monic generator of the ideal of polynomials over $F$ which annihilate $T$.

I would like to know how to prove the uniqueness of it, how would I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with proving

> If $f(T)=g(T)=0$ for some polynomials $f,g$, then $\gcd(f,g)(T)=0$

and then the uniqueness will follow from a simple proof by contradiction.